# Приведение NSNumber к double

Tags: foundation, objective-c, ios, xcode

При переводе из NSNumber в double число из 2.3 превращается в 2.2999999998
    `double accum = [self.accumulator doubleValue];`

Обратно такая фишка не работает. Будет выводить 2.299999998

Тут можно как-то без костылей обойтись или нет?
Заранее спасибо за ответ.

Comment: Как создан `accumulator`?

Comment: @property

    (strong, nonatomic) NSNumber *accumulator;

Comment: Ок, а создан он как?

    self.accumulator = ???;

В общем, есть подозрения, что создается оно из float'а, а достается оттуда потом double. И вот на этой конвертации теряется точность.

Answer (score 1):

> При переводе из NSNumber в double число из 2.3 превращается в 2.2999999998

Здесь дело не в переводе, а в невозможности точного предоставления некоторых десятичных дробей в двоичном виде.

> Тут можно как-то без костылей обойтись или нет?

Используйте NSDecimalNumber. NSDecimalNumber наследник NSNumber'а,  но он хранит мантиссу и экспоненту раздельно в целочисленных переменных: мантиссу в переменной типа int, а экспоненту в переменной типа short.

```
NSNumber *number = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithMantissa:23 exponent:-1 isNegative:NO];
```

Ни в коем случае не приводите number к float или double (т.е. не используйте doubleValue и floatValue), иначе потеряете точность.